# C# Console String Parsing of Text File: Only Names or Paths

Tags: c#, string, parsing

I have a C# application which reads text files with lines such as:

```
c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\myfile2.cfm
c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\includes\my file1.blahh4
```

What I need are two values from each lines in such a way:

From line 1:
    `filename` variable valued as 'myfile2.cfm' and `filepath` variable as "" [empty]

From line 2:
    `filename` variable valued as 'my file1.blahh4' and `filepath` as  'includes' [also be \includes\subfolder]

I have tried code like `indexof` and `substring` but no success so far. I think some RegEx should help? Basically, the slashes will be constantly 3 before file or folder names begin.

Thanks!

Comment: Why a downvote? I have over a dozen lines of code where I tried indexOf and substring without success and they would only clutter this space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Path` which parses paths.
Please see the following code for more details:

```
var path = @"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\myfile2.cfm";
var pathFileName = Path.GetFileName(path); // "myfile2.cfm"

var baseDirectory = @"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16";
var pathDirectory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path).Replace(baseDirectory, ""); // ""
```

**Edit** See the code below which sets the paths to LowerInvariant in order to ensure the replace works as expected.

```
var baseDirectory = @"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16".ToLowerInvariant();
var paths = new string[] {
    @"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\myfile2.cfm",
    @"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\includes\my file1.blahh4"
};

var sanitizedPaths = new List<Tuple<string,string>>();
foreach(var path in paths.Select(p => (p ?? String.Empty).ToLowerInvariant()))
{
    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(path);
    var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(path).Replace(baseDirectory, String.Empty);

    sanitizedPaths.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(fileName, directory));
}

// sanitizedPaths[0] -> "myfile2.cfm" | ""
// sanitizedPaths[1] -> "my file1.blahh4" | "\includes"
```

**Edit 2** Using `Uri` and based on the fact your base directory is always 3 segments, the following should do:

```
var paths = new string[] {
    @"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\myfile2.cfm",
    @"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\includes\my file1.blahh4",
    @"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\includes\subFolder\other file.extension"
};

var sanitizedPaths = new List<Tuple<string, string>>();
foreach (var path in paths.Select(p => (p ?? String.Empty).ToLowerInvariant()))
{
    var uri = new Uri(path);
    var pathWithoutBaseDirectory = String.Join("/", uri.Segments.Skip(4));

    var fileName = Path.GetFileName(pathWithoutBaseDirectory);
    var directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(pathWithoutBaseDirectory);

    sanitizedPaths.Add(new Tuple<string, string>(fileName, directory));
}
```

Comment: Thanks. The pathFileName is correct but the pathDirectory is still coming to the full paths. They need to be either "" or something like 'includes' or 'includes\subfolder'. Note, the subfolders can be 'includes' or 'images' etc

Comment: See the edits, it should work as expected using LowerInvariant now

Comment: Thank you. I am already in loop where lines are being read. A finalParts[0] variable has the full path name per line. Your code original is correctly extracting the filename but not the correct path.

Comment: As you mentioned the base directory is always 3 segments, using Uri might work. See the edit 2 and let me know. Thanks.

Comment: Thank you very much again. Your Edit 2 code is working for me. Yay!

Answer (score 1):

Use `Path` class to get file names and file directories:

```
var baseDirectory = @"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\";
var files = new[]
{
    @"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\myfile2.cfm",
    @"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\includes\my file1.blahh4"
};
```

And here goes LINQ query

```
var query = from file in files
            let directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(file)
            select new
            {
                filename = Path.GetFileName(file),
                filepath = directoryName.StartsWith(baseDirectory)
                        ? directoryName.Substring(baseDirectory.Length) : ""
            };
```

Output:

```
[
  {
    filename: "myfile2.cfm",
    filepath: ""
  },
  {
    filename: "my file1.blahh4",
    filepath: "includes"
  }
]
```

Comment: Thank you. Your output is good but I am already in a big file read While loop. I need to incorporate your logic in my loop. Will take time.

Comment: @Meengla if file names are lines in your big file, then you can use `File.ReadLines("fileName")` instead of `files` array in my code. You also can select more data in LINQ query (not just filename and filepath). Or you can use same code in your loop. Just define `var directoryName = Path.GetDirectoryName(file);` as local variable and use it to get filepath

Comment: Thank you. It's more than file names on each line--there are four values per line; the first being full file path. And I am trying to extract file names and required paths from that first value.

Comment: Hey, @StfBln Answer working with much less code. I DO appreciate your detailed help so much!!

Answer (score 1):

What I would do is use the FileInfo class in a recursive loop to get a list of all files.  You can separate the path and filename using the FileInfo.  Then using the string length of the base folder you are acting on and substring that from the path of each of the files.

Something like this?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            RelativePaths p = new RelativePaths(@"u:\test");
            foreach (var str in p.MyFiles)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(str);
            }
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }

    class MyFileInfo
    {
        public MyFileInfo(string path, string filename)
        {
            Path = path;
            Filename = filename;
        }

        public string Path { get; private set; }
        public string Filename { get; private set; }

        public override string ToString() => $"{Path}, {Filename}";
    }

    class RelativePaths
    {
        List<MyFileInfo> myPaths = new List<MyFileInfo>();

        public RelativePaths(string startingPath = @"U:\test")
        {
            DirectoryInfo dir = new DirectoryInfo(startingPath);
            PathSeparator(dir.FullName, dir);
        }

        public MyFileInfo[] MyFiles => myPaths.ToArray();

        public void PathSeparator(string originalPath, DirectoryInfo dir)
        {
            // Files in dir
            foreach (var file in dir.GetFiles())
            {
                myPaths.Add(new MyFileInfo(file.DirectoryName.Substring(originalPath.Length),
                                           file.Name));

            }

            foreach (var folder in dir.GetDirectories())
            {
                PathSeparator(originalPath, folder);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Original paths:

u:\test\subfolder

u:\test\testfile1.txt

u:\test\subfolder\fileinsub1.txt

u:\test\subfolder\subfolder2

u:\test\subfolder\subfolder2\two deep.txt

Where result is:

, testfile1.txt

\subfolder, fileinsub1.txt

\subfolder\subfolder2, two deep.txt

Note that the results are in a list of type MyFileInfo so you can just use the data output however you see fit.  This is only and example.  You may want to create a static class with an extension method instead but using the recursive method to look in each folder is the concept that might be helpful.  Note you can copy the source code directly into a new console project and run it in Visual Studio just change the starting path.

Comment: Please note that PathSeparator is a recursive method.

Comment: Will your code make the path as "" or 'includes\subfolder' or 'includes' or 'images' or 'images\subfolder' ?

Comment: I will add example out in anwser.

Comment: I am going to implement your solution; hopefully, it will fit in my code where everything is being done inside a FileRead While loop. Thanks so much!!

Comment: so in my While loop, I have finalParts[0] which contains the full path  such as c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\add_service.cfm  ; what I need to do is to call your code and get the return values per the original Question. Any idea?

Comment: Hey, @StfBln Answer working with much less code. I DO appreciate your detailed help so much!! –

Comment: @Meengle Yes just call: var files = (new RelativePaths(@"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16")).MyFiles

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
var s1 =@"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\myfile2.cfm";
var s2 =@"c:\ecpg\BL_Publish_Staging_CFCS_PSC_Outage_Notification_16\includes\my file1.blahh4";

var filename = Path.GetFileName(s1);
var p1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(s1);
if (!p1.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(@"\includes"))
    p1 = "";
var p2 = Path.GetDirectoryName(s2);
if (!p2.ToLowerInvariant().Contains(@"\includes"))
    p2 = "";
```

Comment: Hi, the subfolder can be 'images' or 'includes' and sub-sub folder can be like 'images\subfolder